# How to find out table name from an array of records in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am getting result from two different queries fired on two different tables. Then I am merging these two arrays. Now I want to find out table name from each entry in the array.

```
@notification_challenges=Challenge.where("to_id=? and activity_id=?" ,current_user.id,@activity.id)
@challenge_ids=[]

@notification_challenges.each do |l|
  @challenge_ids=@challenge_ids<<l.id
end

@match_results=MatchResult.where("challenge_id IN (?) and result_confirmation_status=?" ,@challenge_ids,1)

      @notifications=@notifications+@match_results
      @notifications=@notifications+@notification_challenges
puts @notifications
```

Result of this is :

```
[#<MatchResult id: 10, no_match: false, winner_id: 1, runner_up_id: 4,  first_confirmed_by: 1, result_confirmation_status: 1, ch
allenge_id: 11, created_at: "2015-06-30 13:06:36", updated_at:  "2015-06-30 13:06:59">, #<Challenge id: 11, to_id: 1, from_id: 4
, activity_id: 1, datetime: "2015-06-24 18:36:11", description_challenge: " ", acceptance_status: 1, created_at: "2015-06-30 13
:06:13", updated_at: "2015-06-30 13:06:28">]
```

Now I want table name i.e. MatchResult or Challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to check class name as your question looks, use `.class` method.

```
@notifications.map { |n| b.class }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the class and table_name method i.e `@notifications.map { |n| n.class.table_name }`

Answer (score 0):

I just modified ans posted by jon snow because I want class name.

```
@class_names=[]
@notifications.each do |i|
     @class_names=@class_names<<i.class.name
end
```